# Old PS2 or O.G. Xbox video game where a sorcerer takes control of armor

Tags: story-identification, video-games

PS2 or O.G. Xbox game:

- Sorcerer has to take control of knight's armor that is on display to use to get across a bridge.
- The first mission starts off in a battle; you play as knight then though the mission you meet the elf and the wizard or sorcerer
- The enemy of that mission were kinda like orcs

That's all I can really remember.

Comment: Thanks but That's not it sorcerer was a good guy